What is an elastic collision?
In an elastic collision, is the kinetic energy of the individual object conserved, or the kinetic energy of a system as a whole.
If it is true that the energy of the whole system is conserved, how is an elastic collision different from an inelastic collision?

What part of your definition is not enough? Elastic=conserved, inelastic=not conserved....

In an elastic collision process, the energy of the system as a whole is conserved, however, for an inelastic process, the system energy is not conserved. It is well known that when a system is acted on by external forces, that the total system energy will not remain constant, however, internal forces may also alter system energy if they are of a dissipative nature.
In the inelastic case, the internal forces involved in the collision process are non-conservative or dissipative and tend to cause system energy loss, i.e. from internal friction, radiation of sound heat and light, etc. By contrast, elastic collision processes involve only internal forces that are non-dissipative, thus the system energy remains constant.

I would have said, "... kinetic energy..." The total energy of any system is always conserved if you draw the right boundary to define "the system."

@SolomonSlow It seems to me that "external force" exactly specifies the force as outside the system boundary and therefore capable of causing changes in the system energy.

OK, but imagine a system consisting of two balls of putty in free-fall. They collide, and they stick together. Is the energy of that system, as a whole, not conserved? In the moment after the collision, more of the energy is in the form of thermal energy, and less of it is kinetic energy as compared with the moment before, but is it not still the same total energy?

@SolomonSlow If your system is the two balls of putty, then no, the energy of the system is not strictly speaking conserved. Why? because some of the thermal energy is radiated away from the system into the universe which is external to the system. Now if you expand the sytem to putty balls + universe, then yes the total energy is conserved.

I was considering the limit as the interval of time between "the moment before" the collision and "the moment after" goes to zero.
